# Making all the keys value in an array of objects blank

Tags: javascript

How to make all the key's value in an object replace with blank values...

```
var array = [{key1:'value',key2:'value2'},{'key1:'value',key2:'value2}]

for (item in arrayObj) {
    arrayObj[item] = ' ';    
}
```

Is the above code right...

Comment: for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
document.write("<b>arr["+i+"] is </b>=>"+arr[i]+"<br>");
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
  for (var item in array[i]) {
    array[i][item] = ' ';    
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [{key1:'value',key2:'value2'},{key1:'value',key2:'value2'}]

for(var i = 0, size = array.length; i < size; i++){
    for(var key in array[i]){
        array[i][key] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    document.write("<b>array["+i+"] is </b>=>"+array[i]+"<br>");
}
```

That's probably the best answer for this question =D

Comment: this is an array print, which is probably more educational than a straight answer.